# How to display content of every node using one node in Firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure saved in my database:

[image]

What I want is I want the databaseReference to recognise the entire node using only the unique `imageUIDh` and display the content of all fields like `postedAtTime`, `postedOnDate` etc.

Is this possible in `Firebase`? Is there some alternative to achieve what I want?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query)

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.orderByChild("imageUIDh").equalTo(imageUIDh).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Hope this helps :)